# How to build new columns based on the unique initial letters from a dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pandas, dataframe

I have thousands of hostname, those i want to be assigned into different columns based on their first initial three letters. I see this can be done if its small list ans i know the initial letters but i have huge list.

I have google a lot but did not get any proper hint, tried `df.assign` but that's something not great fit.

### Example hostname:

```
fox001
fox002
fox003
fox004
fox005
fox006
dbx001
dbx002
dbx003
dbx004
dbx005
dbx006
trd001
trd002
trd003
trd004
trd005
trd006
spl001
spl002
spl003
spl004
spl005
spl006
```

### What is expected:

```
fox_host   db_host  trd_host spl_host (<-- column names)
fox001     dbx001   trd001   spl001
fox002     dbx002   trd002   spl002
fox003     dbx003   trd003   spl003
fox004     dbx004   trd004   spl004
fox005     dbx005   trd005   spl005
fox006     dbx006   trd006   spl006
```

### my dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('inventory_hostanme',header=None).rename( columns={ 0:"hostnames"})
print(df)

hostnames
fox001
fox002
fox003
fox004
fox005
fox006
dbx001
dbx002
dbx003
dbx004
dbx005
dbx006
trd001
trd002
trd003
trd004
trd005
trd006
spl001
spl002
spl003
spl004
spl005
spl006
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) to group the column `hostnames` on the first `three` letters of the host value, then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) along `axis=1` to concat each of the grouped dataframe creating a new dataframe with separate columns for each hosts:

```
hosts = pd.concat([
    g.rename(f'{k}_host').reset_index(drop=True)
    for k, g in df['hostnames'].groupby(df['hostnames'].str[:3])], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
# print(hosts)

  dbx_host fox_host spl_host trd_host
0   dbx001   fox001   spl001   trd001
1   dbx002   fox002   spl002   trd002
2   dbx003   fox003   spl003   trd003
3   dbx004   fox004   spl004   trd004
4   dbx005   fox005   spl005   trd005
5   dbx006   fox006   spl006   trd006
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham for the help +1, i will check this with my current list and getback on the results.

Comment: @.Shubham,  can you please explain `g.rename(f'{k}_host')` and `for k, g in df['hostnames']` this will make me understand the login behind the scene as i am in learning phase.

Comment: As far `for k, g in df['hostnames']` is concerned we are iterating over each grouped series, where `k` refers to group key i.e `the first three letters of `hostname` and `g` refers to the grouped series itself, so for every iteration we are renaming the grouped series to desired format using `g.rename()`. So for example for the grouped series with k=`dbx` we rename it as `dbx_host`

Comment: thank you. .. is there any good link to practice about these loops  ,  i will seek your mentor-ship.

Comment: Basically i am not ware of any such link but i will suggest you to look in [offcial pandas guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html), it has number of great resources.

Comment: And there is always `StackOverflow` where you can find interesting questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

`cumcount` with `.groupby` of the first 3 characters in your column returns `0,1,2,3,4` for each group of letters. From there, pivot the dataframe and change the column headers:

```
df['a'] = df['hostnames'].str[0:3]
df['index'] = df.groupby(['a'])['a'].transform('cumcount')
df = df.pivot(values='hostnames', columns='index').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
df.columns = df.iloc[0].str[0:3] + '_host'
```

output:

```
    dbx_host fox_host  spl_host     trd_host
0   dbx001   fox001    spl001       trd001
1   dbx002   fox002    spl002       trd002
2   dbx003   fox003    spl003       trd003
3   dbx004   fox004    spl004       trd004
4   dbx005   fox005    spl005       trd005
5   dbx006   fox006    spl006       trd006
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @David,  i think `df['fox001'].str[0:3]` you mean `df['hostnames'].str[0:3]`,  +1 , though i will check this.

Comment: yes, sorry, I read the first row as header when copy and pasting your dataframe. I have updated.

Comment: @kulfi , apologies - there was a typo. It is fixed.

Comment: Thanks so much David, would mind explaining about last two line in the post that will help me to understand.

Comment: `df = df.pivot(values='hostnames', columns='index')` transforms the dataframe into the output that you want; however, it includes lots of `NaN` cells, which you need to use `.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))` to clean up. `df.columns = df.iloc[0].str[0:3] + '_host'` takes the first row with `.iloc[0]` and the first 3 characters of each cell with `.str[0:3]` in that first row and adds `_host` to the end of each string and sets those values as the column headers with `df.columns`.